# How to skip matched records in outer join?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario where I want to skip matched records against a particular product in outer joined table. What thing I am missing in my query? What else I have to mention in my where clause to achieve desired query.

Customer_Profile table.

```
 USER_ID        
 110            
 111    
 112
 113
 114
```

Services table.

```
 USER_ID            PRODUCT_NAME
 110                'Daily Offer'
 119                'Daily Offer'
 120                'Daily Offer'
 110                'Another Offer'
```

Required result set. If 110 opted for 'Daily Offer', I want to skip it only. If 110 opted for another offer, it will be the part of required result set.

```
 111    
 112
 113
 114
```

Query I tried:

```
SELECT C.USER_ID FROM CUSTOMER_PROFILE C 
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICES S ON C.USER_ID = S.USER_ID
WHERE (S.PRODUCT_NAME <> 'Daily Offer' or S.PRODUCT_NAME is NULL)
```

Which is giving following output. How can I skip 110 USER ID?

```
 110
 111    
 112
 113
 114
```

Comment: True, but since it's coming with another product name, just want to skip this row.

Answer (score 1):

Why Not this

```
SELECT C.USER_ID 
FROM CUSTOMER_PROFILE C 
WHERE C.USER_ID NOT IN( SELECT S.USER_ID
                        FROM SERVICES S 
                        WHERE S.PRODUCT_NAME = 'Daily Offer' OR S.PRODUCT_NAME is NULL
                        GROUP BY S.USER_ID   
                        HAVING COUNT(S.USER_ID) = 1
                      )
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/58997/20)**

Comment: It's giving me the desired result. But I am just wondering if I can do it without using NOT IN clause. And doing it only through simple condition in WHERE clause.

Comment: @TahirAkram May be alternative way. I have updated code with Having clause. It will work. May other answer is as you expected but it will failed when you add new row in Customer as  `115` and service as `115, 'office'`.  [**Check Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0f478/1)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you really want:

```
SELECT C.USER_ID,s.* 
FROM CUSTOMER_PROFILE C 
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICES S 
ON C.USER_ID = S.USER_ID and S.PRODUCT_NAME <> 'Daily Offer'
WHERE  S.PRODUCT_NAME is NULL
```

With `s.*` to see what's the difference between your code and mine.

Sql Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9025a/4).

Answer (score 0):

Just change the join to not equal to like this:

```
SELECT C.USER_ID 
FROM CUSTOMER_PROFILE C 
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICES S ON C.USER_ID <> S.USER_ID
OR (C.USER_ID = S.USER_ID AND S.PRODUCT_NAME <> 'Daily Offer')
```

Comment: If 110 did not opted for 'Daily Offer' then I want him to appear in my result set. With above query a person who opted for any offer will get filtered. Any further idea?

Comment: @TahirAkram that wasnt in the question description ;) fixed it though

Comment: I tried your query in this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71e94/15 but it does bring 110 USER_ID.

Comment: oops, forgot that I cant filter on the second table if i dont join it first. fixed it

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT C.USER_ID
FROM CUSTOMER_PROFILE C
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(PRODUCT_NAME = 'Daily Offer') has_offer, USER_ID
    FROM SERVICES GROUP BY USER_ID
) S ON C.USER_ID = S.USER_ID WHERE has_offer = 0 OR has_offer IS NULL;
```

`MAX(PRODUCT_NAME = 'Daily Offer')` per user will be `True` if and only if the user has at least one daily offer, which I believe is exactly what you want.

EDIT: This, however, will print the user only once if he has more than one offer. You can print him multiple times by adjusting the query slightly:

```sql
SELECT C.USER_ID
FROM CUSTOMER_PROFILE C
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    (
        SELECT MAX(PRODUCT_NAME = 'Daily Offer') has_offer, USER_ID
        FROM SERVICES GROUP BY USER_ID
    ) F
    INNER JOIN SERVICES S
    ON F.USER_ID = S.USER_ID
) ON C.USER_ID = S.USER_ID
WHERE F.has_offer = 0 OR F.has_offer IS NULL;
```